# How to Redirect to specific Login page based on host-name in IIS using URL Rewrite?

Tags: iis, rewrite

I have an IIS website that is mapped (binding) to two separate sub-domains. Let's say x1.domain.com and x2.domain.com

How do I create a rule in URL Rewrite so that I can redirect the user to a specific login page based on host name?

Users requesting x1.domain.com should see x1-login.html as the default page.
Users requesting x2.domain.com should see x2-login.html as the default page.

Note: It should only perform this redirection when the user requests using only the sub-domain in the browser. Such as http://x1.domain.com or https://x1.domain.com or http://x2.domain.com or https://x2.domain.com

It should not perform redirection if the requested address is included in the path or query string.

Regards.

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 You can find examples to check host names in conditions.

Answer (score 1):

To create a rule in IIS URL Rewrite to redirect users to specific login pages based on the host name (sub-domain) while excluding redirection for requests with paths or query strings, you can use the following steps:

1. Open IIS Manager on your server.
2. Select your website (x1.domain.com or x2.domain.com) in the "Connections" pane on the left.
3. In the "Features View," double-click on "URL Rewrite" to open the URL Rewrite module.
4. Click on "Add Rule(s)" on the right-hand side to create a new rule.
5. Choose "Blank Rule" under the "Inbound and Outbound Rules" section.
6. Configure the rule as follows:

   - Name: Enter a name for your rule (e.g., "Subdomain Redirection").
   - Match URL:

     - Requested URL: Matches the Pattern.
     - Using: Regular Expressions.
     - Pattern: ^$
   - Conditions:

     - Logical Grouping: Match All.
     - Add the following two conditions:

       - Input: {HTTP_HOST}

         - Pattern: ^(x1|x2).domain.com$
       - Input: {REQUEST_URI}

         - Pattern: ^$
   - Action:

     - Action Type: Redirect.
     - Redirect URL: /{C:1}-login.html
     - Redirect Type: Permanent (301).
7. Click "Apply" to save the rule.

This rule will redirect requests to x1.domain.com and x2.domain.com without any path or query string to their respective login pages, such as x1-login.html and x2-login.html. It will only perform redirection when the requested address includes the sub-domain in the host name portion of the URL. Requests with paths or query strings will not be redirected.

Or here is a PowerShell script in case you need to do it on multiple servers:

```perl
# Define the website name and subdomain pattern
$websiteName = "YourWebsiteName" # Replace with your actual website name
$subdomainPattern = "^(x1|x2)\.domain\.com$"

# Define the login page names
$x1LoginPage = "x1-login.html"
$x2LoginPage = "x2-login.html"

# Load the IIS WebAdministration module
Import-Module WebAdministration

# Create the URL Rewrite rule
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\$websiteName" -Filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules" -Name "." -Value @{
    name = "Subdomain Redirection"
    patternSyntax = "ECMAScript"
    stopProcessing = $true
} -AtIndex 0

Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\$websiteName" -Filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='Subdomain Redirection']" -Name "match.url" -Value @{
    pattern = "^$"
}

Add-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\$websiteName" -Filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='Subdomain Redirection']/conditions" -Name "." -Value @{
    input = "{HTTP_HOST}"
    pattern = $subdomainPattern
    negate = $false
} -AtIndex 0

Add-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\$websiteName" -Filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='Subdomain Redirection']/conditions" -Name "." -Value @{
    input = "{REQUEST_URI}"
    pattern = "^$"
    negate = $false
} -AtIndex 1

Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\$websiteName" -Filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='Subdomain Redirection']/action" -Name "type" -Value "Redirect"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\$websiteName" -Filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='Subdomain Redirection']/action" -Name "url" -Value "/$($Matches[1])-$x1LoginPage"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\$websiteName" -Filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='Subdomain Redirection']/action" -Name "appendQueryString" -Value $false

# Commit the changes
IISRESET
```

Replace `"YourWebsiteName"` with the actual name of your website in IIS. Make sure you run this script with elevated privileges (Run as Administrator) and adjust the subdomain pattern and login page names as needed.

This script will configure the URL Rewrite rule for your specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a URL Rewrite rule in your IIS configuration to redirect users to specific login pages based on the host name they use to access the site. Here is an example of how one could write the XML config for your web.config file under the <system.webServer> section:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <!-- Rule for x1.domain.com -->
    <rule name="Redirect to x1-login.html" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^x1\.domain\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="x1-login.html" />
    </rule>
    
    <!-- Rule for x2.domain.com -->
    <rule name="Redirect to x2-login.html" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^x2\.domain\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="x2-login.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

```
<match url="^$" />: Matches an empty URL path; it will only trigger when the user accesses the root domain without any additional path or query string.

<conditions>: Checks the HTTP_HOST: matches sub-domain or not? If so, it does the following:

<action type="Redirect" url="x1-login.html" />: Redirects user to x1-login.html or x2-login.html based on the sub-domain.
```